# Opposite of `read`/`snarf` in Spidermonkey js shell, function to write a string to a file?

Tags: javascript, shell, spidermonkey

Spidermonkey's `js` shell has a nice feature called `read`/`snarf` that can read a file from disk. Is there an equivalent way to *write* files? Nothing like this appears available in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Shell_global_objects) but perhaps someone knows of some undocumented way to do this.

I'm looking for a way to get a large string out of an interactive `js` session. In the browser/Firebug, I'd be able to use `copy` to copy a string to clipboard, or add it to the DOM to copy. In node, I'd use `fs` to write a file.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? I have the same problem. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: @user3050012 sorry, no luck :-/ I went back to Firefox… heh, I'm a bit glad this question didn't get me another Tumbleweed badge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `redirect` and `putstr` functions exposed by the shell like this:

```
const previous = redirect('path/to/your/file')
putstr('stuff to be written')
redirect(previous) // restore the redirection to stdout
```

Or you can use `os.file.writeTypedArrayToFile` to write typed arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If it's of any use to you, I got around this by redirecting terminal output to a file. So all I do is use the 'print' command from the SpiderMonkey shell(which will print to the terminal) and then redirect the terminal output to a file.

Example:

```
//from SpiderMonkey
print('Test - write to file');

//terminal(assume script is called test.js)   
./js test.js >> testFile.txt
```

I am using Ubuntu, but this can be done on all systems. Hope it helps :-)

Comment: i was really looking for a way for a single script to output to multiple files in one shot, without having resort to, say, prefixing indicators to each line and then piping the output to appropriate files…